# How to solve "'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisocalendar'" in django with python

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have made a ***Measurements*** model which has a foreign key relation with a custom user model. I have also a form using this ***Measurements*** model, where the user submits data and stores it in the db. In views the analyze function stores the data of database to a pandas dataframe. I have not used any datetime function.

Whenever I call `runserver` it causes an error like in the title. How should I fix this? For your information: ***Measurements*** model has a `DateTimeField`.

Here is my model:

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    d_value=models.IntegerField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(UserSignupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

here is the views:

```
def analyze(request):
    qs=Measurements.objects.all().values()
    data=pd.DataFrame(qs)

    return render(request,'diabetes/analyze.html',{'df':data.to_html()})
```

Comment: ```fromisocalendar``` was added in python 3.8, check your python version.

Comment: my python version is 3.8.0a1

Comment: Try doing a ```dir``` on datetime object to know if this method is supported.

Comment: i think there is some thing wrong with pandas. this problem occurs when i try to import pandas and try to insert the qurey result into a dataframe.